# Append select dict keys to a list

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, dictionary

I am trying to transcribe a sentence into a list of categories (one for each word in the sentence), but keep getting "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'". Any ideas?

```
categories = {
    'direction':["north","south","east","west","down","up","left","right","back"],
    'verbs': ["go","stop","kill","eat"],
    'stop_words': ["the","in","of","from","at","it"],
    'nouns': ["door","bear","princess","cabinet"],
    'numbers': ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"]
    }

sentence = "bear go left eat from cabinet 2."

words = sentence.split()

categorised_sentence = []

for word in words:
    print "---Looking at word:", word
    for category in categories.keys():

        if word in categories.get(category):
            print "===The category is:", category

            categorised_sentence = categorised_sentence.append(category)
            print "***categorised_sentence is: ", categorised_sentence
        else:
            print "hmm..."
```

Comment: `list.append` mutates the instance, it returns `None`.

Comment: What's the alternative then?

Comment: Don't replace your list with that `None`?

Comment: Cheers, all sorted now. Many thanks!